# How to update checkout page on woocommerce using ajax without reloading/refreshing

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using a multistep checkout plugin. Would like to update checkout page (order review information specifically) without having to reload/refresh the page. One of the steps on the multistep has 'add to cart'. Ajax is enabled on Woocommerece settings. Any help would be immensely appreciated.

For multistep, I'm using: http://argthemes.com/woocommerce-multistep-checkout/documentation/

Answer (score 0):

Simply use:

```
jQuery(document.body).trigger("update_checkout");
```

Comment: Thanks for your message. I'm not sure where I should that jQuery. I currently have a .js file and it is asking me to enter the javascript code below:

`$('.argmc-wrapper').on('argmcBeforeStepChange', function(event, currentStep, nextStep) {

     var wizardSteps = $('.argmc-form-steps');
     if (wizardSteps.eq(currentStep-1).hasClass('argmc-billing-step') && wizardSteps.eq(nextStep-1).hasClass('argmc-shipping-step')) {
           //JavaScript code here... 
     }

});`

So, I tried adding jQuery to where it asks to add Javscript code but it is not working. Thanks for your help!